# How to create a SwipeRefreshLayout that only can be pulled outside the RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

I want to create a layout that has for example the main layout is a vertical `LinearLayout`, inside it is a `TextView` and a wrapped `RecyclerView`. I want to add a `SwipeRefreshLayout` that only can be swiped outside the `RecyclerView`.

Here is the simple XML for this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="40dp"
    tools:context=".fragments.warehouse.WHTabOne">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="18sp" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Where should I put the `SwipeRefreshLayout` to make it only works for outside the `RecyclerView`?

Comment: You need to put it below your `TextView`

Comment: I think you need to wrap your textview with a ScrollView and wrap that scrollview with a swiperefreshlayout tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `SwipeRefreshLayout` your root layout and put everything inside it. Example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
    android:padding="40dp"
    tools:context=".fragments.warehouse.WHTabOne">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="18sp" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I was asking for is to prevent the `SwipeRefreshLayout` from starting when swiping on `RecyclerView` only, and swiping everywhere else activate `SwipeRefreshLayout`.

But I found that the `RecyclerView` is by default overrides `SwipeRefreshLayout` until it reaches the top of the RecyclerView then it start to activate `SwipeRefreshLayout`. I thought it won't work because my list was too short and could't notice that. Now that I've added more items to the list, it's clear. So basically, adding everything under `SwipeRefreshLayout` is the right thing by default it will make it in right way.